# How to set color manually in colorpicker eyecon?

Tags: jquery, plugins, color-picker

I am using colorpicker eyecon in my project and i want to set the color manually but when i do that it is set to black color (#000000)

I use `.colorpicker('setValue', value)` method

This is the documentation of this plugin 
http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/

That's my try :

```
$("#button-color").colorpicker();

$("#button-color").colorpicker("setValue", "#ad4747");
```

Comment: Do you just want this done on start up or dynamically?

Comment: I'm just saying if you want it to be a specific colour at start up you can do it in the options when instantiating it.

Comment: Could you produce a fiddle as it's working for me